# Find $f^{(n)}(0) \text{ for } n = 1,2,3,...$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Find $f^{(n)}(0) \text{ for } n = 1,2,3,...$ where 
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{e^x - 1}{x}, & \text{when } x \neq 0 \\
1, & \text{when } x = 0 \\
\end{cases} $$

### My approach

I decided to calculate some first $f$ derivatives. In that case I defined:
$$ g(x) = \frac{e^x - 1}{x} \text{ for } x\neq0$$
$$g'(x) = ...= \frac{e^x x-e^x+1}{x^2} $$
$$g''(x) = \text{..a lot of calculus..} =\frac{e^x x^2-2 e^x x+2 e^x-2}{x^3} $$
$$ g^{(3)}(x) = ... = \frac{e^x x^3-3 e^x x^2+6 e^x x-6 e^x+6}{x^4}  $$
$$ g^{(4)}(x) = \frac{e^x x^4-4 e^x x^3+12 e^x x^2-24 e^x x+24 e^x-24}{x^5}$$
But I don't see a pattern. Some of last factors are $n!$. Denominator is $x^{n-1}$. But for the rest I haven't got idea.

I know also that for $n>0$
$$ f^{(n)}(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{e^x - 1}{x}, & \text{when } x \neq 0 \\
0, & \text{when } x = 0 \\
\end{cases} $$
so theoretically the answer is just $ 0 $ but I am not sure if solution can be so simple...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since$$f(x)=1+\frac x{2!}+\frac{x^2}{3!}+\cdots+\frac{x^n}{(n+1)!}+\cdots,$$then$$(\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}^+):\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}=\frac1{(n+1)!}$$and therefore$$(\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}^+):f^{(n)}(0)=\frac1{n+1}.$$

Comment: Very clever to use Taylor series! But the post has been edited.

Comment: Yes, I had mistake in $\neq$ symbol in function definition

Comment: While this final answer is correct, don't you have to make some argument that $f$ is represented by its Taylor series? If we were talking about analytic functions I'd say this is enough (and jumping to $\mathbb{C}$, making this argument, and then restricting back to $\mathbb{R}$ would also be valid). But I know that "things can go wrong for real functions".

Comment: @JonathanZ What could go wrong here? Since$$(\forall x\in\mathbb{R}):e^x-1=x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\dots,$$then$$(\forall x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}):\frac{e^x-1}x=1+\frac x{2!}+\frac{x^2}{3!}+\dots$$Furthermore, $1+\frac0{2!}+\frac0{3!}+\cdots=1$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos could you explain why you are threat $f$ without "if $x=0$ then $1$" case?

Comment: @trolley But I **did* treat the case “of $x=0$ then $f(x)=1$” in the last sentence of my previous comment! From your point of view, what is missing?

Answer (score 1):

$$y:=\frac{\exp(x)-1}{x}$$
We multiply both sides by $x$:
$$xy=\exp(x)-1$$
We differentiate both sides wrt $x$:
$$y+xy'=\exp(x)$$
Doing it again:
$$y'+y'+xy''=\exp(x)$$
$$2y'+xy''=\exp(x)$$
And again:
$$2y''+y''+xy'''=\exp(x)$$
$$3y''+xy'''=\exp(x)$$
And I think we can see the pattern now:
$$(n+1)y^{(n)}+xy^{(n+1)}=\exp(x)$$
And now let's substitute in $x=0$:
$$(n+1)y^{(n)}(0)=1$$
$$y^{(n)}(0)=\frac{1}{n+1}$$

Comment: Your solution is clever, but why we can ignore orginal brace-form function and consider just function $y:=\frac{\exp(x)-1}{x} $?

Comment: @trolley Well, $f$ is the only possible continuous extension of $y$, so it's "not a big deal". In my derivation, I assumed that $y^{(n)}(0)$ exists $\forall n$, which implies that $y(0)=1=f(0)$. And we would need to check if my assumptation is correct or not.